# What is the reason of intensive users corpora growth?

Tags: discussion

Today number of users grows on about 50, thus total number of users increased by more than 10%.

Many of this new users immediately started to answer questions. I can only welcome it, all I'm wondering about - what is the reason of such anomaly intensive growth?
As far as I can see, for many of these users these Stack is the first one, so (but I can only guess) it hardly because of internal SE banners.

**UPD:** I've tried to find any kind of links to Russian SE from "outer Universe", but failed to find any (I've used `[link:russian.stackexchange.com] -site:russian.stackexchange.com` query)

**UPD:** indeed, as Quassnoi told, it looks like for some reasons there was a storm of [mentioning Russian SE](http://blogs.yandex.ru/search.xml?text=russian.stackexchange.com&holdres=mark&server=twitter.com&p=0) in twitter.

Comment: I noticed it too... Honestly I don't know the reason yet though.

Comment: We'll see later. So far, experienced users could help us with the information flow by flagging low quality posts, editing poorly formatted answers or reviewing first contributions by new users. =)

Comment: well, I do believe that @anna-lear can shed some light on this issue. There should be at least referrers.

Comment: There were many mentions on Twitter yesterday, with a url shortened by vk.cc. We have probably been mentioned on a Vkontakte group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me first say that I can't share any details, but we have had a major flow of users from external sites where probably we have been named.

The thing might be unstable, by which I mean that user numbers might decrease and not stay stable as they are now, but I believe this might help us in growing even more, even word-of-mouth (virtual or not) works. :P

Comment: We need to try to project the image on the outside that we prefer quality over quantity. People get spoiled by mainstream Q&A sites, and post utter crap sometimes.